# What parameter i have to assign inside my variable so i can start it from my Main?

Tags: c#, siemens, tia-portal

im new to C# and Tia Openness and have an problem. I dont know what parameter goes inside my ImportSingleTextList();.Its an example from Siemens but there is never mentioned how to call it inisde the main. [That is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcJgg.png).

```
private static void ImportSingleTextList(HmiTarget hmitarget)
        {
            TextListComposition textListsComposition = hmitarget.TextLists;
            IList<TextList> importedTextLists = textListsComposition.Import(new FileInfo(@"D:\SamplesImport\myTextList.xml"), ImportOptions.Override);
        }
```

Comment: I would bet on:  var parameter = new HmiTarget(); then inspect parameter to see its properties and figure where you can got them

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried your method it gives me an error "Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments." Dont know what to do anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have a Project instance.  You have to drill down from Project->Device->DeviceItem(->DeviceItem) until you find a DeviceItem that can provide a SoftwareContainer service.  It may be that all such DeviceItems reside at the first level below Device; I haven't checked.  Anyway, here's a method I wrote that searches the first and second DeviceItem levels:

```
public static HmiTarget GetHmiTarget(Device hmiDevice)
    {
        //search first level of DeviceItems
        foreach (DeviceItem di in hmiDevice.DeviceItems)
        {
            SoftwareContainer container =
            di.GetService<SoftwareContainer>();
            if (container != null)
            {
                HmiTarget hmi = container.Software as HmiTarget;
                if (hmi != null)
                    return hmi;
            }

            //search second level of DeviceItems
            foreach (DeviceItem devItem in di.DeviceItems)
            {
                SoftwareContainer subContainer = devItem.GetService<SoftwareContainer>();
                if(subContainer != null)
                {
                    HmiTarget hmi = subContainer.Software as HmiTarget;
                    if (hmi != null)
                        return hmi;
                }
            }
        }
        return null; //nothing was found at the first or second levels

    }
```

to get the Device, you can use PROJECT.Devices.Find(NAME) where PROJECT is your TIA portal project instance, and NAME is the string name of your HMI device.

Comment: Thanks i got it :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to look into your HmiTarget exactly. Is it a class, then you should instantiate a first instance of it; what constructor does this class have - with or without parameters? Click on HmiTarget and see what input it expects.
I guess you class has some kind of enumerable hmitarget.TextLists that you have to fill or get too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it and it says that it is an Class when i click on it and it says that it represents the target device. I dont know how to give him the info about the target device. It doesnt accept Strings or Ints. Im lost. Still thanks a lot